# RでcreateDataPartitionが見つけられない

Tags: r

`install.packages("caret")` をダウンロードしたが、createDataPartitionを使うことができない。

createDataPartitionを使用できるようにするためにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。良ければ教えてください。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `caret` ライブラリをロードする必要がありまして、`require("caret")` を実行します。

Comment: ありがとうございました。